# Differential analog to the Lebesgue spaces $\mathcal{L}^p$

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, lp-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, big-picture

I am looking for a differential analogue to the Lebesgue spaces $\mathcal{L}^p$ in the following sense:

The integral behaves badly for functions with too much mass i.e. such whose tails decay too slow and/or whose singularities diverge too slowly. This leads $\int f d \mu = \infty$ and it makes it impossible to compare two functions (by their integral). However, if we make some modifications $f$ to $f_p$ for varying $p$ s.t. at least for some $p$ we have $\int f_p d \mu < \infty$ and keep track of the modification, then we can work properly with it. This is what the $p$-norm captures. The modification in question is of course raising the absolute value to the power $p$.

Functions in $\mathcal{L}^p$ i.e. with finite $p$-norm should then be seen as "modification $p$ makes the integral of $f$ finite". In the case of measure spaces were there are no sets with arbitrary small, positive measure or in the case of spaces with finite measure we have the embedding theorems. In those cases, this modifications become linearly ordered, making it more reminiscent of a valuation. In general one at least has the interpolation embedding: $\mathcal{L}^p \cap \mathcal{L}^q \subseteq \mathcal{L}^r$ for any $r \in [p, q]$.

I would like to consider a similar modification scheme for differentiability. Thats is, I am looking for a gradual way to smooth out functions, of which I am able to keep track. My first approach was to consider convolution with functions of certain regularity and then keep track of the regularity of that function. But that seems to be too strong, since convoluting any function with a $C^k$ function yields something in $C^k$. However, I would like to have something like "up to regularity $\alpha$ the convolution is still not differentiable, but convoluting with anything above regularity $\alpha$ makes the convolution differentiable". But I think that convolution with special functions yields the right notion.

I am sure something like this has already been explored by someone at some point? Does it sound familiar to you?

I would very much appreciate any pointers/references.

Comment: This concept is known and quite important. You can look up for example Sobolev spaces or Besov spaces. I can also recommend reading the following article https://www.google.com/amp/s/terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/04/30/245c-notes-4-sobolev-spaces/amp/

Comment: I don't hink Sobolev spaces are what I am looking for as the Sobolev norm concerns the integrability of the derivative. In the Sobolev sense, a function with a "hard cusp" i.e. when the derivative has a singularity but diverges very fast there, it is "good" while something having a soft cusp does not. I am also not sure if Besov spaces are the right concept.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what are you looking for, but note that Sobolev norms do capture some information about local smoothness (not only integrated derivatives) because there exist embedding theorems, which tell you that knowledge of sufficiently many integrated weak derivatives can be traded for knowledge about boundedness. In particular function which is in all Sobolev spaces is actually smooth. Furthermore you mention convolution, which has very nice and simple properties with respect to Fourier transform, which is closely related to the Sobolev norms.